# jQuery .click Function with If Statement Only Works for the .show() Case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to the whole jQuery scene so I do apologise if I'm being dumb however I've tried my hardest to resolve this myself.

I am using jQuery to manipulate a CSS UL menu. I've got a jQuery which works for 3/4 of it's requirements. jQuery finds any items in the UL with children and appends a span to them. The span is used to house a drop down arrow to open the sub-menu.

Clicking the sub-menu opens it okay and clicking anywhere on the page hides the sub-menu okay with the $(document) function I've added, but for some reason, once the sub-menu is open, the second half of the if statement in the .click function doesn't close the menu.

Any thoughts? Platform is WordPress and the menu is generated by wp_nav_menu for what it's worth.

Non-functional part of the jQuery script is the second half of the if statement after the else.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.sub-menu-wrap').parent().append('<span> v </span>');
$('ul.nav-menu li span').hover(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('hover');
})

$('ul.nav-menu li span').click(function() {
    if(!$('div.sub-menu-wrap').is(':visible')) {
        $('ul.nav-menu li span').parent().addClass('drop');
        $('ul.nav-menu li span').siblings('a').addClass('drop');
        $('div.sub-menu-wrap').show();
    } else {
        $('ul.nav-menu li span').parent().removeClass('drop');
        $('ul.nav-menu li span').siblings('a').removeClass('drop');
        $('div.sub-menu-wrap').hide();
    }
})

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    var container = $("div.sub-menu-wrap");
    if (!container.is(e.target)         
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
        {
        $('ul.nav-menu li span').parent().removeClass('drop');
        $('ul.nav-menu li span').siblings('a').removeClass('drop');
        $('div.sub-menu-wrap').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Now with added HTML.

```
    <div class="nav-menu-wrap">
    <ul class="nav-menu" id="menu-navigation-menu">
    <li class="first-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-251" id="menu-item-251"></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-261 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-271" id="menu-item-271">
    <div class="sub-menu-wrap" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-441" id="menu-item-441"></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-461" id="menu-item-461"></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-451" id="menu-item-451"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span> v </span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-241" id="menu-item-241"></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-211" id="menu-item-211"></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-201" id="menu-item-201">li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-221" id="menu-item-221"></li>
    <li class="last-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-231" id="menu-item-231"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify what is the problem?

Comment: I didn't think the HTML was hugely relevant as it looks pretty certain to be my jQuery at fault due to the other bits working but I've added it now. Thanks.

Comment: From the jQuery, document.ready function works perfectly as does the document.mouseup function.

The ul.nav-menu li span .click function, the first half of the if statement with the .addClass and .show() commands works fine, but the second half with the .removeClass and .hide() do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your $(document).mouseup function. It's firing before the click event on your UL, and is hiding the submenu. When you get into the UL click event, the submenu wrapper is hidden, and therefore you're only ever hitting the first condition in your if statement.

If you change the document mouseup to this, it should work. Just added the main menu wrapper to your containers so that you ignore the mouseup event.

```
var container = $("div.sub-menu-wrap, div.nav-menu-wrap");
```

Comment: I have to say though, I don't really understand why adding the parent div to the mouseup works. Do you have a link to the jQuery API which would help me understand it? Thanks.